# Engine Yard with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Greetings,

has anyone of you used the [paperclip](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/paperclip/) plugin on Engine Yards hosting service? Are there any problems to solve or anything to pay special attention to?

Is the [paperclip on heroku](http://github.com/pedro/paperclip-on-heroku) example of Pedro Belo fitting?

Thanks for your comments,
Joe

Comment: Is this programming related? With the funny names they give to things these days, you can barely tell ;)

Comment: Paperclip is an file attachment for Ruby on Rails - and Engine Yard is an Amazon Cloud based hosting provider. Maybe the question is more hosting than programming related! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku and Engine Yard uses Amazon EC2. That's where the similarities stop, though.

Heroku has a very special setup where you don't have write access to the file system. They do that in order to be able to scale easily with their setup, prompting users to use HTTP caching (varnish), S3 and the likes, instead of serving dynamic content via the file system.

Engine Yard has a pretty standard virtual host-ish setup, where you have write access to the file system.

So, the answer to your question is: no, there are no problems or special cases you have to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Using it now on a production site, and I've had no problems thus far.